# Fermat's little theorem with the exponent smaller than the prime number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I encountered this problem that I do not fully understand.

**Find the multiplicative inverse of $[45]$ in $Z_{101}$ . Then
determine the integer x between 1 and 100 such that**

**$45^{99} \equiv x$ (mod 101)**

Using the Euclidean algorithm the multiplicative inverse of $[45]$ can be found as [9].

However finding $x$ is where my effort halts.

Lets denote $a=45$, $e = 99$ and $p = 101$.

Since $p$ is a prime and $a \nmid p$ Fermat's little theorem gives

$a^{p-1} \equiv 1$ (mod p) = $45^{101-1} \equiv 1$ (mod 101)

in a case where $e > (p-1)$ we could simply evaluate $a^e$ as follows

$a^e = a^{k \cdot (p-1) + r} \equiv a^r$ (mod p) where $k$ and $r$ are integers.

Finally $a^r$ could be envaulted in mod p and x would be found.

However, in this problem, $e < (p-1)$ = $(99 < 100)$ and the evaluation described above is not possible. I.e. we can not evalute $45^{99}$ as $45^{k \cdot 100 + r}$.

In summary, how can $x$ be found in the equation

$a^e \equiv x$ (mod p)

when $e < (p-1)$?

Comment: By little Fermat, $45^{100}\equiv 1\pmod {101}$.  Hence $45^{99}\times 45\equiv 1\pmod {101}$, so $45^{99}$ is the modular inverse of $45\pmod {101}$.

Comment: In general, one good way to compute $a^b\pmod c$ is by [iterated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: You just multiply by as many times as the inverse as you have to go down, as per @lulu .  In this case, only once.  In general,  however many times down you need to go (Only useful if that number is relatively small, obviously)

Comment: @lulu yes I see, but how can I use the modular inverse to find x in the equation?

Comment: I don't understand.  By what I wrote, $x$ *is* the modular inverse.

Comment: If you are trying to find $0\leq y<100$ such that $45^{99}\equiv y\pmod{101}$, then use iterated (repeated) squaring as @lulu has already suggested.  Do you understand what is meant by [iterated squaring](http://www.tricki.org/article/To_work_out_powers_mod_n_use_repeated_squaring)?

Comment: Thanks lulu and saulpatz, by looking into iterated squaring it finally clicked.